# Accessing members of the Main class from another class

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, program-entry-point, tabpage

My Windows Forms Application contains some Tabpages for different categories, which contain Treeviews. I have a global search that can find items from that categories (in the category/tabpage the items are nodes in the treeview). When a certain item is found, I want to jump to the right tabpage and the node. Finding the right node wouldn't be difficult but how can I access the Main class and change the selected TabPage in the TabControl from another class?

Comment: Are these custom-built classes?  If so, just pass in a reference to the main class instance when you construct them.

Comment: Harry Potter "ExpectoPatronum"?

Comment: @Adrian makes sense, sometimes I'm stupid.